# docker almalinux help setting up ssh

Tags: docker, ssh

I started an almalinux container as follows:
docker run -it --name ssh-test -p 10022:22 almalinux/9-base

I would like to enable ssh and set an ip once the container is started.
I do get a root prom with the above command but systemctl does not work to turn on services.

docker run -it --name ssh-test -p 10022:22 almalinux/9-base
[root@00d0629ebe5c /]# ls
afs  bin  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
[root@00d0629ebe5c /]#

I need systemstl to enable services

Comment: Running `systemctl` inside a container is in almost all cases an indication that you're doing something wrong (because a container will typically not have a service manager running). If you want to run an ssh daemon inside a container, you run `/usr/sbin/sshd`.

Comment: ...that said, it's also typically an anti-pattern to run an ssh daemon inside a container; you would typically use `docker exec` to run commands inside a running container.